# Getting folder path with Python Tkinter tkFileDialog

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Python Tkinter I am trying to get the directory path of selected Folder. I do not want to load a file or navigate to a file but get the folder path like

[image]

How can I do this?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename

def callback():
    name= askopenfilename()
    print name

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()
```

**Update**

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename
from tkinter import filedialog #for Python 3

def callback():
    name= askopenfilename()

    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print directory

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You added an update, but don't give any context. Is that update showing something you tried that failed? Something you tried that worked? Something else?

Comment: The code is doing same job as opening a file which is not what I want

Comment: I don't understand. The second one is asking both for a filename and then later a directory. I don't see what point you're trying to make.

Comment: I do not need file name. I jst want to navigate to the folder and Select it. Lets say I have a Folder which is Empty and I want to select it. Can you do this?

Comment: That's exactly what `askdirectory()` does. It lets you pick a directory.

Comment: Ok what I need is something [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RElvM.png) which this code is not doing that. As you can see it has `Select Folder` option not `Open`

Comment: There's nothing in tkinter that "opens" a folder. That makes no sense -- you can't (generally speaking) "open" a folder. The function returns the name of the folder. You can then use that to open files in that folder, move that folder, do anything you want with the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok Looks like I find the solution on my own. Putting here which might help someone else in future.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
print(dirname)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use *askdirectory* from filedialog as follows:

```
from tkinter import filedialog #for Python 3
directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is not selecting any folder and just keeps looking to Open folders to select File inside. What I need is to stop after selecting a folder. Please take a look at update